# Почему при обновлении страницы не встраиваются скрипты?

Tags: javascript, webpack

Столкнулся с проблемой при обновлении страницы на странице Main, все работает, если открывать модальное окно то все тоже работает, но если я обновлю на модальном окне, то мне выкидывает ошибку, и даже не знаю как подступиться. При обновлении на мейн ровно этот же скрипт с этим же названием он подхватывает. Обычный рядовой проект на ts, react, styled components, сборщик webpack.
[image: Изображение]

```
export const AppRouter = () => {
    const location = useLocation()
    const state = location.state
    const navigate = useNavigate()

    return (
        <>
            <Routes location={state?.card || location}>
                <Route
                    path={ClientRoutes.MAIN_PATH}    //и открывается и обновляется
                    element={<MainPageLazy />}
                />
                <Route
                    path={`${ClientRoutes.CARD_INFO_PATH}:id`}      
                    element={<h2>скрипты не встраиваются</h2>}
                />
            </Routes>
            {state?.card && (
                <Routes>
                    <Route
                        path={`${ClientRoutes.CARD_INFO_PATH}:id`}      // открывается и не обновляется
                        element={
                            <Modal close={() => navigate(-1)}>
                                <Info />
                            </Modal>
                        }
                    />
                </Routes>
            )}
        </>
    )
}
```